# Secure users data in asp.net web api response

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm completely new to ASP.NET Web API. I've done some research but I haven't been able to find an answer to my problem. I am starting to become very confused about how to secure the data that is being responded to the caller. 
My overall objective is to create an ASP.NET MVC web application and a Xamarain Android application that allow users to register and login into an account and their data stored in a MySQL database.
I thought that a Web API would be a good solution as both applications could call functions to get a collection of users, an individual user and put new users into the database through HTTPPost, HTTPGet requests.

So far I have created an ASP.NET Web API with one controller and one HTTPGet request which returns all the users from the database.
When I run it I get a response of all the user's details.

**My Controller Code**

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Users> Get()
        {
            using (NorthYorkshireContext context = new NorthYorkshireContext())
            {
                return context.Users.ToList();
            }
        }
    }
```

**My Response:**
[image]

If I were to deploy this to a server what is stopping anyone from seeing all the users details? For example, If I deployed this to http://mydomain.co.uk what is stopping anyone from querying the API like http://mydomain.co.uk/api/users and seeing all the details?

P.S I understand passwords should be encrypted, sorry if this is a bad question.

Comment: instead returning DAO object return user without password ....

Comment: @Craig I believe you should take an overview of WebAPI security. You will get the answer yourself once it's clear to you how .NET framework could help you in security aspects. This could be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/

Answer (score 2):

This question reads as *"I created a publicly accessible API endpoint that outputs my entire users table; why are APIs so insecure?"*. Why did you create this operation in the first place? What problem does it solve? When I make a human-sized hole in my house, can I rightfully complain that after a few days my computer and television are stolen?

For each API endpoint you must consider:

- Do I need this? I really can't figure out why you would need a list of all users.
- Do I need this to be publicly accessible, or should it be limited to localhost traffic (i.e. infrastructure)?
- When publicly accessible, who may access it (authorization)?
- When called, should it return all columns that are in its data source, or should there be some kind of mapping?

And no, passwords don't need to be encrypted, they need to be hashed. Use ASP.NET Identity for authentication, don't roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

an API is a perfect solution for what you are trying to do.

When you build an API, that is exposed to the outside world, you need to secure it somehow. This is where something like OWIN, OAuth2 come into place.

A token based system (JWT) is usually a good solution to secure the API. I would start with some reading on the subject if I were you.

Once you secure you API from unauthorized access then you need to think what data you should provide to the users / apps who have the right to access it.

Having passwords in clear is a huge security risk, sending them to the app is an even bigger risk.

Normally you'd let the users authenticate, you would not send passwords to the app.

Make sure your API works over https and do not send anything private in URLs, use POST requests and put the sensitive data in the body.

Security is a big topic, I am afraid.